# Javascript: where do the variables declared in an onload function get attached?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In code where a function is run at **document.ready**:

```
$(function() {
    var vm = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

Where can I find the variable **vm** under **window** in the hierarchy?

Comment: Incidentally, your callback is no fired `onload`, but on [`document.ready`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: Declare it as a global variable, then it will be available as a property of the global object (*window* in a browser).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr:** You can't access it from `window`, unless you put it there.

When you declare a variable inside a function, it is local variable scoped to the function, not a global variable, and is thus not available in the `window` object. You would need to set the variable as a property of `window`.

**Example:**

```
$(function() {
    var vm = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
    window.vm = vm;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `vm`, by definition will not be available in your `window` object. This is because, in Javascript, a new function (as you're doing) creates a new scope. Basically, your `vm` variable is a private variable.

If you want to make this function available you have two options (which are bassicaly the same, but look a bit different):

1 - You can declare your variable outside your function

```
var vm;
$(function() {
    vm = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

2 - You can append it to the window object

```
$(function() {
  window.vm = new ViewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(vm); // vm refers to the vm variable in your window object
});
```

It's good practice to NOT append variables to the window object in any of these ways. You might want to find another way to do whatever it is you want to do. A possibility is executing all your code inside a document.ready (what you're doing) or using a callback function.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere: You declared (used `var`) it inside a function so it is a locally scoped variable.

If you want it available under `window`, then use `window.vm` instead of `var vm`.